# Combining Flexslider with Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, flexslider

I'm combining some jQuery: Flexslider and Masonry.
Flexslider is triggered by global.js:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    // Banner FlexSlider
    $('#side-slider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        slideshow: true,
        smoothHeight: false,
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,
        controlsContainer: ".flexslider-container",
    });

}); // End on window load
```

The masonry is trigger in nwmasonry_init.js:

```
   jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
     var $ = jQuery;

     //Masonry
     var container = document.querySelector('.overzicht');
     var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
       itemSelector: '.bedrijven',
       gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
       transitionDuration: 0,
     }); 
   });
```

On initial pageload, like can be seen here http://nieuws.ditisonzewijk.nl/category/brandevoort/ the slider on the top in the middle overlaps with another content block.

As soon as you resize the window, the slider resizes it's width and therefore the height of the slider is corrected.

Anybody have an idea on how to get the heigth of the slider right on the initial load?

Comment: it might be a timing problem; instead of loading it on  .ready() try .load() event

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [imagesloaded.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#imagesloaded). Overlapping is caused by masonry firing before all the images are loaded. Load the imagesloaded script and try this code:

```
jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
 var $ = jQuery;

 //Masonry
 var container = document.querySelector('.overzicht');
 imagesLoaded(container, function() {
 var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
   itemSelector: '.bedrijven',
   gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
   transitionDuration: 0,
 }); 
 }); 
 });
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I've just tried that, but I see some errors in the console:

EventEmitter is not a function and container.imagesLoaded is not a function

Comment: I then get: Uncaught TypeError: EventEmitter is not a function and Uncaught ReferenceError: imagesLoaded is not defined

Comment: you are not loading imagesLoaded.js

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Put it in the wrong functions file. However, now that I've done this correctly, I get no more errors, but the problem with the overlap still exists.

Comment: You most likely need to put your Banner Flexslider code above: ````$('#side-slider').flexslider({...});  ````inside the imagesloaded function as well since those images are part of masonry container.

Comment: Done that, but it doesn't change anything. I don't think the image not being loaded is the problem. The slider and the masonry grid can both resize after imagedimensions change.
The problem seems to be that the width of the Flexslider UL is pagewidth in the initial state. After resize the width of the slider is only the masonry container it is in and that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fix for this, even though it isn't pretty. I've put a delay on the masonry init.

```
function loadMasonry() {    
***fire masonry***    
}        
setTimeout(loadMasonry, 500);
```

Now it's working correctly. Anybody an idea on how to fix this properly?

Comment: Or I could fire Masonry from within the Flexslider 'start function' property. (Fires when the slider loads the first slide.) That seems like a better option.